# Cant seem to make drop down stay active when I go to choose an option

Tags: html, css

I cant really describe the issue that well other than that when I hover the menu appears no problem but when I move the mouse down to select an option it closes again.

In the real version of the site I will be using images instead of the background-colors so it would be great if I could keep the transition without breaking anything.

The code I am currently using for the drop downs is as follows:

```
#navigation ol#nav-holder li ul.dropdown{
display:none;
}

#navigation ol#nav-holder li:hover ul.dropdown{
display:block;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/c2aah2as/  < To show the issue in more detail.

I have never ran into an issue like this before when creating drop downs so I hope I am just missing something simple!

Hope this is understandable.

Thanks, 
Luke.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is caused by `<div id="nav-bottom">` which stays on top of the menu and interrupts hovering. Issue can be fixed by raising the *z-index* of the `<li>`-element on top of `<div id="nav-bottom">`.

Comment: Awesome, Knew it was something simple! Any idea how I could stop the background image showing up in the sub menu? (the li items inside the dropdown ul) EDIT: even with changing the z-index it doesn't seem to work properly..

Comment: `nav-bottom` *z-index* is 9999. Did you raise `ol#nav-holder li` to at least 10000? On the fiddle it seems to work.